# How to render in commerce-product.html.twig calculated price?

Tags: 8, commerce

I can render calculated price via {{ product.variation_price }}

Is it any chance to this price from product_entity variable in twig? I have used custom resolver class to update price.

**updated at 16/06/2020**

I`m using resolver class to made some calculations with price. And all changes goes to product.variation_price variable. In product_entity price left initial without calculations. The main problem that i want to divide output for product.variation_price separately price and currency. I have price in USD but should output price in EUR. and get currency without price is not so obvious

Comment: Question is not very clear, please provide some more information

Comment: All this should be part of your question, edit your question so anybody that reads it is clear as to what you are asking.